# Filter Related Tables in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Let's say I have a table of Companies, a table of Employees, and the Employees table has an FK column to the Companies table. It's very easy to query the companies and return the related employees.

```
var companies = from c in Companies
                select c;
```

It's very easy to filter those companies by adding a `where` clause. But how can I filter the employees returned in the query above. For example, to only include those employees where the Employed column in true?

I'd like to return all companies, with only those employees who are currently employed.

Comment: The example you've given doesn't return the related employees.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: How so? My example was actually made up and doesn't reflect my real code. But it returns related data in the real code.

Comment: Because this doesn't explicitly load in the employees for the companies, it won't load them into memory when this query is evaluated. If you're iterating over the `companies` and then accessing their `Employees` properties, you'll be lazily loading each batch of employees one at a time, which would cost a lot of database round-trips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve the companies and their employees which are employed:

```
var companies = from c in Companies
                select new
                {
                    Company = c,
                    EmployedPersons = c.Employees.Where(e => e.Employed)
                };
```

Used like so:

```
foreach (var company in companies)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", company.Company);
    foreach (var employee in company.EmployedPersons)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", employee);
    }
}
```

Another approach, based on your comment that you need to filter this elsewhere:

```
public void DisplayEmployedPersons(Company company)
{
    foreach (var employee in company.Employees.Where(e => e.Employed))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", employee);
    }
}
```

Lastly, you could modify the partial class generated for your `Customer` data object:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> CurrentEmployees
    {
        get { return this.Employees.Where(e => e.Employed);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's close. But I don't want to filter the companies. Just the employees.

Comment: As in join the companies and employees retrieving just those who are employed?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow that completely. I'd like to return all companies and include only those related employees who are employed. I'm fairly new to this but I know a join is done automatically for me. Can I replace the automatic join with a custom one somehow?

Comment: Perhaps that can work but it would be more like `c.Employees = c.Employees.Where(e => e.Employed)`. I was hoping to simply limit some of the employees--I do not have another field to hold the results.

Comment: @Jonathan: Firstly, you can't reassign `c.Employees` like that unfortunately. Secondly, what do you mean "do not have another field"? In your code or in the database?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Yes, I could see that might be a problem. In your code, you assign the result to `EmployedPersons`. I'm just saying I don't really have a place to store the results. Rather, I just want to pass the company object with the related employees filtered. Looks like this is not as simple as I'd hoped. I guess I'll just return all related employees and filter them after the fact?

Comment: @Jonathan: That is what my example is doing. It returns a new, anonymous, object with the company and its employed persons. For clarification, where and to what are you "passing" this?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I'm passing it to a control that expects a collection of Company objects. That's why I was saying I didn't want to create a new, different object, as your code does. But it looks like I have no choice.

Comment: @Jonathan: if this is EF4, I've updated to provide a partial class example.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Thanks. Once the data has been retrieved from the database, I know how to work with it. I was just hoping to make the filter I've described part of the actual SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the employees, but here's a way to iterate through them:

```
var companies = from c in Companies
                where c.Employees.Any(e => e.Employed)
                select c;

foreach (var company in companies) {
    foreach (var employee in company.Employees.Where(e => e.Employed)) {
        // your employed employees are iterated here
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't quite work, because `companies` won't have an `Employees` property.

Answer (score 2):

Using *query* syntax:

```
var companies = from c in Companies
                from e in c.Employees
                where e.Employed
                select c;
```